# Application: Should I disclose my sex, where (another) one is given priority in the job advertisement?

Tags: applications

> "Applications from women are expressly welcome and will be given
> priority in accordance with the State Equal Opportunities Act.
> Severely disabled applicants and applicants,  who have the legal
> status of being equivalent to being severely disabled, will be given
> special consideration if they have the same qualifications,
> suitability and qualifications. We are happy to receive applications
> from members of our volunteer fire department."

I am *not* with their fire department (not living in that township; the job is not with the fire department, they just encourage to be a volunteer firefighter), I *am* severely disabled (which gets the employer a reimbursement of 75% of his costs), I am no woman but neither a man, thus hiring me would rise the diversity there while not rising their ratio of women. The employment is in the German civil service. What would be (dis-)advantages/is it common practice to state your sex in the application?

Notes: This is not about whether to tell them at all: if they hire me, they will get it for example from my insurance number - in case they really accomplish to not notice it before. And this is not about gender but about sex (maybe about sex *and* gender).

My name is on my certificates/testimonials, they would guess a wrong sex from it, and even if it would be neutral, this would mean that it could be given to any sex, not only to divers. (At least I am not aware of any divers-only names in the used language, but several neutral ones.)

The State Equal Opportunities Act (yet) only treats men and women.

Comment: Do you need to disclose your name on the application?  Is your name sufficiently neutral that they would not be able to guess your sex?

Comment: Do you know how the State Equal Opportunities Act treats non-binary people? Is it possible that the wording of the Act means that it should apply to you as well? I'd look it up but apparently multiple places have something called this. (Also, adding a location to your question would be helpful.)

Comment: @Kilisi I'm not sure that this is an application for a fire fighter, only they are welcome to apply to whatever this position is. Either way, there are jobs at a fire station that severely disabled people would be great at, aside from fighting fires. Like answering calls, community outreach, etc., let's not jump to conclusions...

Comment: Do you think they are going to make a hiring decision without ever talking to you face to face, via video call, or in the phone?

Comment: @mxyzplk A lot of hiring decisions (especially the decisions not to hire) are made without ever talking. I have been hired without talking (in all but one of my previous paid positions), and applications have been rejected without talking (and even some with talking).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should I disclose my sex, where (another) one is given priority in the
> job advertisement?

There's no need to disclose that you aren't a woman. Omitting that will tell them what they need to know. But you *should* disclose all attributes which would give you special consideration.

Since you indicate you are severely disabled, and the advertisement indicates that severely disabled applicants will get special consideration, it only makes sense to bring it to their attention.

Answer (score 1):

What you quote is something many companies add to their job descriptions to come across as tolerant and open-minded. I have seen that in many job ads. I've also worked in companies praising themselves to be extra tolerant but found no correlation between their declarations and the level of discrimination.

Having said that, your status as a disabled person may play a role for financial reasons. You may want to mention that.

But I wouldn't devote that more than a short mention (and obviously not mention your sex/gender) in your application documents. Unless you're applying for low-pay positions, in which your status as disabled can make or break your application.

And no, sex/ gender is not an aspect to bring up in your application.

Comment: Well, I compete with people for jobs for which the employer receives money (in contrast to getting back only 75% of their expenses).